# Flexbox CSS column to row

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need to have information moved from being in one column to being in four rows once the viewport reaches 750px using flexbox:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  text-align: center;
}

section {
  border: inset #333 thin;
  padding: 1em;
  /
}

.animals {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.minerals {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: rgb(255, 30, 218);
}

.vegetables {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: rgb(233, 255, 30);
}

@media screen (min-width: 750px) {
  .body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="animals">
  <header>
    <h2>Animals</h2>
    <h3>DNC</h3>
  </header>
  <main>
    <section>
      <h4>Animal One</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Virtutis, magnitudinis animi, sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h4>Animal Two</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Virtutis, magnitudinis</p>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h4>Animal Three</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Virtutis, magnitudinis animi, fortitudinis fomentis dolor mitigari solet. Omnes enim iucundum motum.</p>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h4>Animal Four</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
    </section>
  </main>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are applying your flex styling to the wrong element - if you apply it to the main element - and then alter that in your media query - you will be able to swap between the layouts.

Also note that you had a typo in the media query - you need 'and' between the screen and the width (this is actually two declarations - the screen is to enforce the styling to screen layout as opposed to say - print layout and then the width is to apply at the given width...

To view the difference - open the following snippet in full screen mode to see the horizontal layout.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  text-align: center;
}

section {
  border: inset #333 thin;
  padding: 1em;
 
}

.animals {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.minerals {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: rgb(255, 30, 218);
}

.vegetables {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: rgb(233, 255, 30);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 750px) {
  .wrapper {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  section  {
        min-width:0;
        flex: 1 1 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="animals">
  <header>
    <h2>Animals</h2>
    <h3>DNC</h3>
  </header>
  <main class="wrapper">
    <section>
      <h4>Animal One</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Virtutis, magnitudinis animi, sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h4>Animal Two</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Virtutis, magnitudinis</p>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h4>Animal Three</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Virtutis, magnitudinis animi, fortitudinis fomentis dolor mitigari solet. Omnes enim iucundum motum.</p>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h4>Animal Four</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
    </section>
</main>
</div>
```